# iOS UITableview simple drop down within table

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

Wandering if anyone can help with iOS table view.

Background:

Ive got 4 entities:

RecordDate (relationship - records one to many with RecordWorkout)

RecordWorkout (relationship - recExercises one to many with RecordExercise)

RecordExercise (relationship - sets one to many with RecordSet)

RecordSet

Currently i am displaying the data through 4 different tableview controllers.

What I am after is to display the last 3 entities in one view controller as a drop down table.

Is this possible?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: what is a "drop down table"? do you mean a navigationController with tableViews? or do you want to expand sections within a tableView? some pictures would be great.

Comment: Expand sections within a tableView. I shall add some pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com/) has extensions for both collapsable sections and expandable tree view. Try running the [Collapse](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Collapse/Collapse/CollapseTableViewController.m) and [Outline](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Outline/Outline/OutlineTableViewController.m) sample projects. If I understand your question, you've got a two-level hierarchy, so either of these extensions should work.

The main difference between the two is that, with collapsable sections, the top level is done with section headers while the tree view is all done with cells. Also, collapsable sections has scroll optimization, such that when you expand a section, it automatically scrolls to display as much as the section as possible (though scroll optimization will be added to the tree view at some point).

Comment: Thank you for your response. i will have a look through this :)